# How to add a logger to a LogContext

Tags: java, mapreduce, log4j2, hadoop2

I am going to write a Hadoop 2.x MapReduce program. Usually the logs or any output from Mapper or Reducer of a MapReduce job is logged in an YARN application log. But I am the most interested in the happening inside the Mapper. So **I would like to use log4j2 inside the Mapper to log into a separate  local file on each data node**.

My plan is to initialize a `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext` at the beginning of the Mapper so that I can reconfigure a separate log file, and then initialize a `org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger`. The problem is that both are initialized successfully, but they are not connected to each other. Moreover, only the node calling the hadoop job initialized the empty log file.

My question is:

- Why only the node calling the Hadoop job initialized the empty log file, other nodes did not even though I am sure that other nodes also have the mappers.
- How to add the logger to the initialized log context

Answer (score 0):

The default ContextSelector is the ClassLoaderContextSelector, which creates a LoggerContext based on the ClassLoader being used. Every call to getLogger() checks to determine the ClassLoader of the caller of getLogger and uses the LoggerContext associated with that classes ClassLoader.

If each Mapper has its own ClassLoader then each will have their own LoggerContext. But each LoggerContext has to be able to locate its configuration and initialize it. If log4j2.xml is not on the classpath of the ClassLoader (or its parent) then it will use the default configuration, which probably isn't what you want.

I haven't written a Mapper and am not really familiar with that, but based on your description I would say that what you probably want to do is use the Configurator class to initialize logging in each Mapper and pass in the configuration you want to use.  Note that you should NOT have the configurations try to write to the same files. You would either have to use file locking or you may get corrupted files.

Comment: How can I know if the Mapper has its own ClassLoader or not? Hereby I also would like to mention that a Map Reduce class is a static class, which I embedded it in another Class and the map function is inside this static map reduce class. An example is here: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Example:_WordCount_v2.0